# Why signal handler can't reached?

Tags: c, signals

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void sighandler(int signo)
{
    extern void __gcov_flush(); 
    __gcov_flush(); 
    printf("reach here \n");
}
__attribute__ ((constructor))
void ctor()
{

    signal(SIGINT, sighandler);
}
```

then PRE LOAD the built so with one main app which run without sleep.
I call "kill -s 2 pid", but the log can't be printed? So why doesn't it work?

Comment: What's that #endif in the middle of the code?

Comment: Did you check that ctor() gets called?

Comment: Does your Output get Printed when you move it before __gcov_flush?

Comment: You should add main function (which sleeps Forever or whatever) and make the code a complete program, showing the problem. http://sscce.org

Comment: I am sure the ctor be called.

Comment: update the code , I think the code is very simple,but it doesn't work.